# Using recordPlot with lattice

Tags: r

Recently I became aware of the `recordPlot` command in R that lets you save figures to then use `replayPlot` to re-use them as necessary. This works with base R plots without issue:

```
my.plots <- vector('list', 5)
for (i in 1:5) {
    plot(i)
    my.plots[[i]] <- recordPlot()
}

pdf('Test.pdf')
for (i in 1:5) {
    replayPlot(my.plots[[i]])
}
dev.off()
```

However, when I try to set up a similar approach with `levelplot` (a plot from the `lattice` package), I receive an error. Specifically, I get `Error in recordPlot() : no current device to record from`, when using something like:

```
my.plots <- vector('list', 5)
for (i in 1:5) {
    temp <- matrix(rnorm(25), 5, 5)
    levelplot(temp)
    my.plots[[i]] <- recordPlot()
}

pdf('Test.pdf')
for (i in 1:5) {
    replayPlot(my.plots[[i]])
}
dev.off()
```

How can I use a similar construction with `lattice` plots?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is even easier with lattice plots (or any plots, e.g. `ggplot` output, based on grid graphics): in this case the plots themselves are R objects, and can be stored and printed later. The code is basically identical to yours, it just replaces storing the output of `recordPlot()` with storing the plot object itself, and replaces `replayPlot()` with `print()`.

```r
my.plots <- vector('list', 5)
for (i in 1:5) {
    temp <- matrix(rnorm(25), 5, 5)
    my.plots[[i]] <- lattice::levelplot(temp)
}
pdf('Test.pdf')
for (i in 1:5) {
    print(my.plots[[i]])
}
dev.off()
```

Comment: Took me longer than I care to admit to even ask the question, which was then answered within seconds. Typical! Thanks for the great and straightforward answer.